# Git hanging on POST git-receive-pack

Tags: git, ssl, tortoisegit, git-extensions, bonobo

I am having trouble pushing large changes or files, around 20MB, to Git. It will always hang after POST git-receive-pack and displays

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0

I have seen the other questions on StackOverflow but none of them work. However, I did try many things so hopefully this extra information can help find a solution.

I set up Bonobo Git Server using IIS and http without SSL certificates and everything works fine. I can push/pull large files with TortoiseGit, GitExtensions and also use Visual Studio 2015 Community. Obviously this is insecure without encryption.

The problem arises when I set up Bonobo using https and SSL certificates. I created the CA and Server certificate using makecert and pvk2pfx and installed the certificates in Windows store. The website works fine and I can pull and push small changes. However, when I try to push a large file it hangs at the message POST git-receive-pack even when using Git GUI. But Visual Studio 2015 Community will work fine! Once I push using VS I can then use Git to pull those changes on another computer. This leads me to believe it is an issue with Git and not the Bonobo server.

The things I had to do was add the SSL key to bundle.crt and set postBuffer = 524288000. I also tried sslVerify = false to test for an SSL issue but this did not work. I also tried turning off my Windows Firewall.

Is this an issue with Git and SSL? Is there something else that needs to be set up? I'm new to Git and trying to get this working for a few days now. Using Visual Studio is a workaround for now but it would be nice to be able to use other Git clients directly in Windows. I have the latest version of Git, 2.7.0, and I believe when I tried GitExtensions it installed a pre release version, I think 1.9

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution on the Bonobo website.

> **SSL and large repositories**
>
> When using SSL and pushing large repository you should increase the
> variable size as described above and if it still doesn’t help you
> should apply the following Microsoft patch ([KB2634328](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2634328)).

I haven't seen this answer anywhere on StackOverflow so hopefully this information helps anyone searching this site.

Comment: Thanks for this. I am not using Bonobo but TFS and had this issue with some larger Repos and this fixed it for me where `http.postBuffer` increases did not.